# Asynchronous requests best practice in Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-4, asynchronous, background

In my application I use background jobs for offloading work to the background. That is for CPU intensive operations as with IO ones. I wonder is there a preference on that in case of doing asynchronous requests. I mean I also use BG jobs for making my requests async, which I feel not the best way to go, considering some other alternatives like EventMachine.

So what is the best practice for implementing asynchronous requests?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about Rails 4 here:

1. Rails ActionController::Live module, check out [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#live-streaming-of-arbitrary-data).
2. web socket, [websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails) is one wrapper of its implementation.

Comment: the `websocket-rails` gem was last updated on Jun 5, 2014... it doesn't seem to be in active development. look into [ActionCable](https://github.com/rails/actioncable), Faye, [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket) or [Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) (I'm biased, being Plezi's author).